# Hiding the action bar causes bottom aligned item in RelativeLayout to jump

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-relativelayout

i have `RelativeLayout` with a view that is aligned to the parent bottom. when i call `actionBar.hide()` the view slides up as the action bar slides up, then once the action bar has fully disappeared, the view jumps back to the bottom.

how do i prevent this from happening? i want the view to stay attached to the bottom as the action bar slides up.

[can't embed images so here's a link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjaQR.gif)

the tabs are what are bottom aligned. (the grey stuff you see above is a different fragment being loaded so ignore that)

Code:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(...) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main);
    }
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getActivity().getActionBar().hide();
    }
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        getActivity().getActionBar().show();
    }
}
```

R.layout.fragment_main:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="test" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please share the code here.

Comment: Share the code please :)

Comment: @fsociety Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 8):

Set action bar overlay mode in your AppTheme style:

```
<item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
<!-- Support library compatibility -->  
<item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
```

[(more info)](http://android.xsoftlab.net/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html)

and, if you need, set padding or margin in your layout file like this: `?android:attr/actionBarSize`

Comment: A bit annoying to have to set the margin/padding on every layout, but this is the only solution that worked for me